# Joint Convexity of functionals

Tags: calculus-of-variations

This is a transcript from *The Calculus of Variations* by
Jeff Calder

> For the given functional $F(x,y,y')$, the sufficient conditions for a
> weak solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation to be a minimizer is that
> we require *joint convexity* in $y$ and $y'$.

As a counter-example, we can take:

> $F=\frac{((y')^2-\lambda^2 y^2)} {2}$

which has been claimed to be *non-convex*.
However, I don't know how to verify that. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A twice differentiable function is convex if only if its Hessian matrix is positive semi-definite at every point. We have
$$ F''(x,y,y') = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -2\lambda^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}, $$
and so, if $\lambda \neq 0$, the Hessian is never positive semi-definite since it has one eigenvalue $<0$.